# How can I tell which declared dependencies I am not using in my R package?

Tags: r, dependencies, r-package

Assume that I have been developing an R package while strictly tracking dependencies via a file e.g. `mypackageR-package.R` which may look something like this:

```r
#' @keywords internal
#' @importFrom dplyr filter mutate select arrange
"_PACKAGE"
```

In the next development iteration I change the code and thus become completely independent of e.g. `dplyr::arrange()`. In such cases I would like to remove the dependency since it is no longer required and I only want to track what I really need.

Is there an "automatic" way to figure out which dependencies are unused by the current setup/code base of a package?

Comment: if you run your package checks do you get any warnings about unused imports? you can use `devtools::check()` to test your package

Comment: Alternatively, if it's as simple as checking for a couple specific functions,  Just run a Search across all source files in the editor of your choice.

Comment: @Mike on `R version 4.0.5` with `devtools 2.4.2`, `devtools::check()` I get no such warning.

Comment: ok, I saw this thread and it might have a good lead to use a function that closer resembles R CMD checks: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1427

Comment: Also tried on `R version 4.3.2` with `devtools 2.4.5`, and `devtools::check()` shows no such warning.

Comment: For the record `R CMD check` did also not return useful output for me with respect to the question here.

Comment: You could brute-forcely remove each import at a time and run the check, if it fails, it is needed. You could write a simple loop which  does that automatically for you. By the way, this is the very reason, why I always use fully qualified references in my code (except operators like `%>%`) becasue it makes it easy to search in all files for references of a given packages (e.g. search for `dplyr::` to see whether the `dplyr` import is still needed)

Comment: Some more context: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2459